# Acess JSON object correctly

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, element

I'm trying to access the elements in the JSON object that I have returned from the server. The structure of the JSON is as follows:

```
    ajaxResponse: 
           {
           "user":{
                "0":"Matt",
                "name":"Matt",
                 "1":"/images\/peopleImages\/test.jpg",
                 "image":"/images\/peopleImages\/test.jpg"
                },

           "comment":{
                "userCommentID":21,
                "userComment":"vc ",
                "userID":1
              },

         "error":false

        }
```

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of:

```
              ajaxResponse[0].user.name
              ajaxResponse.user.name
              ajaxResponse.user['name']
```

But nothings working I always get the type error is undefined.
Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT

This is how I'm getting the JSON

```
          $.post( "script.php" ,
                {
                    task: 'commentInsert',
                    userId: commentUserId,
                    postId: '2',
                    userComment: comment                    
                }                                   
            ).success(
                function(ajaxResponse){     
                    console.log("response: " + ajaxResponse);
                    console.log(ajaxResponse[0].user.name);
                    /*
                    ajaxResponse[0].user.name
                    ajaxResponse[0].user.image

                    ajaxResponse[0].comment.userCommentID
                    ajaxResponse[0].comment.userComment
                    ajaxResponse[0].comment.userId
                    insertComment($.parseJSON(ajaxResponse));                   
                            */      
                }   
            ).error(
                function(){             
                    console.log("error" );              
                }   
            );
```

Comment: missing `"` at `1"` ....then `ajaxResponse:` ?????

Comment: Are you getting a valid object for `ajaxResponse.user`?

Comment: check your JSON here first: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Are you sure ajaxResponse is defined as you expect it to be?

Comment: That was just a typo - its fine in the json I get back- which I've just restructured here to be easier to read. Yes ajaxResponse is correct - I jsut cant access it correctly.

Comment: I just validated it, everything is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I forgot to call `parseJSON`

```
      var data = $.parseJSON(ajaxResponse);

      console.log("response2: " + data.user.name);
```

That seems to correct it and allows to me to get the name back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While returning content from your server :

```
echo json_encode($ajaxResponse);
```

while sending POST :

```
dataType: "json"
```

Based on this you might get it in :

```
ajaxResponse.user
```

try consoling it.

Answer (score 0):

For a direct use of Json object you need to inform the dataType = "json", then you can use $.ajax from jQuery to send post values and correct data type.

See documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {
          task: 'commentInsert',
          userId: commentUserId,
          postId: '2',
          userComment: comment
    }
    success:  function(ajaxResponse){     
                console.log("response: " + ajaxResponse);
                console.log(ajaxResponse[0].user.name);    
            }   ,
    dataType: "json"
});
```